# Is there another word for 'beyond earth'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I've used 'extraterrestrial' twice in a paragraph already, so it's starting to get repetitive...

Edit: The sentence I'm hoping to prove is 'Humans have reached *[insert word]* scales', referring to the furthest we've went in the universe.  By reaching I mean actual physical human presence, which excludes anything discovered or photographed by probes, and limits us to the Moon.  Hence, the question is to find a word describing Earth-Moon scales.

In response to the numerous suggestions below:

- **Unearthly or cosmic scales** is too grand and fails to convey what I'm gunning for - a sense of humility and a slight disappointment at
  the lack of human achievement in interplanetary matters ever since
  the completion of the Apollo program.
- **Alien scales** just sounds plain silly.
- **Extrasolar, interstellar, or intergalactic scales** are factually incorrect.

So far, **off-planet** seems to suit my purpose the best for now.

Comment: As an adjective or a noun? Are you talking about little green men?

Comment: Have you consulted a thesaurus? What did you find? (That's the obvious answer here, so please do demonstrate that you have already done that so it's not suggested)

Comment: Also give us some context please. An example sentence or two.

Comment: And buy everyone a round of drinks while you're at it

Comment: For what unearthly reason do you need such a word?  What in heaven's name are you writing?  Does you story involve otherworldly beings?

Comment: *cislunar*? *extraorbital*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second part of the sentence, the term *scales* is awkward. Which makes this answer off-topic, but so be it.

> Humans have travelled beyond what was thought humanly possible.
>   Humans have continually pushed the limits of space travel.
>   Like the starship [Enterprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Enterprise), humans continue to go where no man has gone before.

If you need a term that means beyond the Earth's orbit but within its galaxy, I think you could use  **interstellar**, but I'm not an astrophysicist, so you might need to check up on that.

EDIT (I read the question more carefully)

> Humans have failed to physically explore beyond the Earth's orbit.
>   Humans have travelled no further than the Earth's orbit.

Comment: I've completely misunderstood the OP, and the request. Oops!

Answer (score 2):

Context is everything, so here are some examples for a variety of contexts.  *Off-planet* would be entirely reasonable in earth-based SF, for example.  Or you could use specifics (anthing like *orbital* -- earth-orbit implied, *Martian*, *Betelgeusian*).  Then you've got *galactic*, *extrasolar* (for beyond the solar system)...

Answer (score 1):

You may use ***cosmic***:

> - of or relating to the regions of the universe distinct from Earth. (AHD)

Comment: Ah, what I meant was: I often point out that voting on this site is highly irrational.  I meant: **"Since voting on this site is highly irrational, this answer, which is superb, was downvoted."**

Answer (score 1):

There is the obvious ***alien***.

> *adjective* :  from somewhere other than the planet earth
>   *noun* :  a being that comes from somewhere other than the planet earth
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alien)</sub>

But, there is the less used, but perhaps more obvious, ***unearthly***.

> :  not terrestrial
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unearthly)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Interplanetary** doesn't seem to be on anyone's list yet. **Post-Terrestrial** seems an acceptable neologism for your purposes.

Simple, metaphorical phrases might also serve your purpose: "Humans took their **first steps** beyond **the cradle of Earth** on Mars, paused on the **stepping stones of Asteroids**, then, in the great photosphere of Jupiter, stood tall on Io."

Comment: You had me at **interplanetary**.

Answer (score 0):

Lots:
**Cislunar**
**Jovian**
**Andromedan**
Just pick somewhere else.